# Resolve a string from a Ember model computed promise

Tags: ember.js, promise, ember-data

I have a computed property on an EmberJS model:

```
imageUrl: computed('image', function () {

    let promise = new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve('image.png');
    });

    //
    return DS.PromiseObject.create({promise: promise});
}),
```

Which works, however the model resolves the promise to an object so I have to do something like:

```
resolve({image: 'image.png'});
```

To actually access the value in the template, using something like:

```
{{result.imageUrl.image}}
```

Rather than just:

```
{{result.imageUrl}}
```

Obviously the problem appears to be to do with `DS.PromiseObject` but I have no idea what to use instead and the docs are not very helpful in this regard.

Comment: just a tip: in es6 `{promise: promise}` as the following shorcut : `{promise}`

Answer (score 4):

DS.PromiseObject proxies the result to its content field. If you pass in just a string, you can retrieve it using `{{result.imageUrl.content}}`. However, if you return an object, a call to `{{result.imageUrl.image}}` will use the proxy, so that when you `get` the image it will be mapped to `content.image`.

Personally, I prefer to use `ember-concurrency` for my async needs:

```
import { readOnly } from '@ember/object/computed';
import { task } from 'ember-concurrency';

fetchImage: task(function* () {
  return yield 'image.url';
}),

imageUrl: readOnly('fetchImage.lastSuccessful.value')
```

See the documentation for the [ember-concurrency](https://ember-concurrency.com) addon to see if it is appropriate for your needs.